# How to increase size of serial number in OL

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the size of the number in OL without increasing the font size of the text of the content.

What is wrong with this and how to correct it:

```
<ol style="font-size:5em">
    <li style="font-size:1em">Hello </li>
</ol>
```

All I want is big number 1 with font-size of 5em with 1em text size of the content Hello.

Also I need to use only inline style.

Comment: You want the numbers of the `ol` to be `5em`, but the text of the `li` elements to be `1em`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The numbers of the `li` elements are formatted according to the CSS rules for the `li` elements themselves; therefore to style the numbers differently to the text you have to wrap the text itself into another element (in this case a `span`):

```
<ol>
    <li><span>list element one</span></li>
    <li><span>list element two</span></li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style: decimal-leading-zero;
    font-size: 5em;
    margin: 0 0 0 2em;
}

li span {
    font-size: 0.25em;
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style: decimal-leading-zero;
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 0 0 0 2em;
}
li span {
  font-size: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><span>list element one</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>list element two</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7EZ4e/).

If you're able to sacrifice certain older browsers that can't handle generated content, then you could use, instead:

```
<ol>
    <li>list element one</li>
    <li>list element two</li>
</ol>
```

and:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: listNumbering;
}

li {
    font-size: 1em;
    counter-increment: listNumbering;
}

li:before {
    content: counter(listNumbering,decimal-leading-zero) '.';
    font-size: 5em;
}
```

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: listNumbering;
}
li {
  font-size: 1em;
  counter-increment: listNumbering;
}
li:before {
  content: counter(listNumbering, decimal-leading-zero)'.';
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>list element one</li>
  <li>list element two</li>
</ol>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7EZ4e/1/).

Revisiting this answer, it seems that the `::marker` pseudo-element is beginning to be more widely adopted (albeit behind flags in Chrome and Edge 80+, as of writing). This means it may be a better option than the above in the relatively near future:

```
li {
  /* something of a magic number to position the ::marker
     on the page: */
  margin-left: 2em;
}

/* the generated list-marker for the <li> element: */
li::marker {
  color: #f90;
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

Please note that the below snippet – and the above CSS – requires a compatible browser, some browsers such as Chrome, Chromium and Edge in versions 80 and above require that `enable-experimental-web-platform-features` flag be enabled, whereas in Firefox 68+ it should work).

```css
li {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

::marker {
  color: #f90;
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>list element one</li>
  <li>list element two</li>
</ol>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/53ewkcgd/).

References:

- [`counter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter).
- [`counter-increment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment).
- [`counter-reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset).
- [`::marker` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) ([compatibility](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_marker_animation_and_transition_support)).

Comment: Cannot believe that there is no direct CSS targeting of only the numbers possible as of 2017, and that we still need a "workaround".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS pseudo-element [**::marker**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker). (Demo snippet below.)

```
ol li::marker {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```css
ol li::marker {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Hello</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<ol>
    <li style="font-size: 3em"><span style="font-size: .5em">Hello</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: My original answer was applying the style to the wrong elements. You want the styles attached to the `<li>` and the `<span>`, as currently shown.

Comment: @AgA - Because when you style the `li`, you're also styling the ordered list numerator. http://jsfiddle.net/F4cDm/

Answer (score 0):

See this [tutorial](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/style-your-ordered-list).

```
ol {
  font: 5em;
}

ol p {
  font: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Note: The `p` in that example is actually another element not present in the OP's markup.